# Splitting the asymptotic upper density

Tags: number-theory

Let $d(X)$ be the asymptotic upper density of a set of positive integers $X$, namely 
$$
d(X):=\limsup_{x\to \infty}\frac{|X\cap [1,x]|}{x}.
$$

Notice, for example, that if $X=\cup_{n\ge 1} [(2n)!,(2n+1)!]$, then $d(X)=d(X^c)=1$.

Now, let us take an infinite subset $E$ of *even* numbers, and let's call $O$ the set of *all odd* numbers. Is it necessarily true that
$$
d(E\cup O)=d(E)+\frac{1}{2}\,\,?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N,$ and if $A$ has upper density $\alpha$ and $B$ has **density** $\beta,$ then $A\cup B$ has upper density $\alpha+\beta.$ This follows from the fact that, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exists, then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n.$$